# Find and remove duplicate entries where values can be swapped between two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following data structure which contains relationships between nodes. The `relationships` table has a `from_id` and `to_id` the values in these can be swapped.

I need to find and remove ONLY the duplicates leaving a single row of each pair.

```
| id    | node_from_id  | node_to_id |
---------------------------------
| 1     |   100         |   200      |
| 2     |   200         |   100      |
| 3     |   200         |   300      |
| 4     |   300         |   200      |
| 5     |   200         |   300      |
| 6     |   300         |   400      |
| 7     |   500         |   400      |
```

After removal of duplicates I'd like the following to remain in the table

```
| id    | node_from_id  | node_to_id |
---------------------------------
| 1     |   100         |   200      |
| 3     |   200         |   300      |
| 6     |   300         |   400      |
| 7     |   500         |   400      |
```

I am able to return all the rows that match relatively simply but to enable them to be removed I only really want to return the actual duplicates to allow one of the key pair rows to remain.

Here's my query which currently returns ALL matching rows

```
SELECT *
FROM relationships AS rel1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
    FROM relationships AS rel2
    WHERE
        rel1.id <> rel2.id
    AND
    (
        (
            rel1.from_id = rel2.from_id AND
            rel1.to_id = rel2.to_id 
        )
        OR
        (
            rel1.from_id = rel2.to_id AND
            rel1.to_id = rel2.from_id
        )
    )
)
```

I thought I might be able to use a window function and select only the rows with `row_number() > 1` but I don't seem to be able to use that inside the EXISTS sub query.

I have made the actual data for `relationships` [available as CSV](http://www91.zippyshare.com/v/lD2KZ38i/file.html) if that helps

Comment: Does it matter about which exactly rows will be removed? 
Or you just need unigue?

Comment: Exactly, which one remains doesn't matter as long as one remains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use smth like

```
select  min(id),
        least (node_from_id, node_to_id) node_from_id,
        greatest(node_from_id, node_to_id) node_to_id
from    relationships
group   by         
        least (node_from_id, node_to_id) ,
        greatest(node_from_id, node_to_id)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this almost works, but it also includes rows that don't have duplicates

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't understand the problem. It returns 1,3,6 and 7 rows as you requested. If you need to remove the rows which were not initially duplictaed (6,7) as well, just add `having count(*) > 1` in the end.

Comment: Sorry you have mis read, the table of data represents what would be left in the table after a delete

Comment: Add having fixes it! Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- SELECT * -- to test  which rows will be deleted
DELETE      -- to actually delete     
FROM ztable zt
WHERE zt.node_from_id > zt.node_to_id
AND EXISTS(
        select *
        FROM ztable nx
        WHERE nx.node_from_id = zt.node_to_id
        AND nx.node_to_id = zt.node_from_id
        );
```